# Chrome's Mystery Popup That Can Be Moved Around

Tags: javascript, html, selenium, google-chrome, web

I was looking through the Chrome Webstore, and I noticed a popup (or alert) that I didn't know existed, it pops up, but it allows you to move the window around? not only is it able to be moved around, but it can also be moved out of the original window as if it was a new tab (which it very well may be). Here is a GIF showing what I am talking about:

[Click Here For The Image!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/COIXb.gif)

Below is a snippet of a regular HTML alert that most people are familiar with, however, as you can see from running the script, you can't move around the popup like you can with the Chrome Webstore's popup.

```html
<div style="display: flex;justify-content: center;align-items: center;">
    <button onclick="tryme()">
        try me
    </button>
</div>
<script>
    function tryme() {
        window.alert("sometext");
        console.log("working")
    }
</script>
```

The reason that I was really interested in finding how to make this is so that I could automatically accept it with something such as a python-based selenium web driver. Selenium has a tool where you can switch to an alert, but it is unable to recognize this alert due to it not being a generic alert. So if we could find out how this popup worked we could figure out how to automate tasks with it...

When looking at the HTML for the button that triggers this popup I split it up into two parts, this first section is the HTML **before the click**:

```
<div role="button" class="dd-Va g-c-wb g-eg-ua-Uc-c-za g-c-Oc-td-jb-oa g-c" aria-label="Add to Chrome" style="user-select: none;" tabindex="0">
    <div class="g-c-Hf">
        <div class="g-c-x">
            <div class="g-c-R  webstore-test-button-label">
                Add to Chrome
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Below is the HTML of the button **after the click**:

```
<div role="button" class="dd-Va g-c-wb g-eg-ua-Uc-c-za g-c g-c-oa" aria-label="Checking..." aria-disabled="true" style="user-select: none;">
    <div class="g-c-Hf">
        <div class="g-c-x">
            <div class="g-c-R  webstore-test-button-label">
                Checking...
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When looking for the JavaScript function that drove this popup I found the following:

[Click Me For The Image!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HwbS9.png)

When looking for the definition of that Javascript function/method I found the following:

```
ep = function() {
    var a = gp
      , b = function(c) {
        return a.call(b.src, b.listener, c)
    };
    return b
}
```

Although that obviously didn't help much, and from here I decided to ask all programmers' Lord and savior Stack Overflow for assistance.

Comment: That prompt is outside of the DOM.  (You can't click it without user-intervention or a "robot" type of class.)  It's the browser's own prompt.... similar to ones that would allow access to location or camera/audio.  If you need that extension installed in the browser, you need to install it when starting up the driver. (Or use an existing profile with it already installed?)

Comment: @pcalkins is right. But if you're curious, the call that seems to create the popup is chrome.webstorePrivate.beginInstallWithManifest3(callerObject, callback(result, unknownVar){}, arguments). You can see more information in the debugger if you put a breakpoint before this statement in the beginInstall function.

Comment: @pcalkins Awesome, thank you so much, I wasn't aware that you could boot chrome with an extension installed, through Selenium. That answers my question.

Comment: @Kevin I will continue to look into it, thank you so much for your response!